# Getting a javascript alert while loading the page without pressing a $_POST button

Tags: javascript, php, post

In my page `updel.php` I have this code:

```
$text = $_POST['detail'];
$uren = $_POST['uren'];
if (empty($text )) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Gebeurtenis field must be filled\")</script>";
}
else if (empty($uren)){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Uren field must be filled\")</script>";
}

else if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE eventcalendar SET Detail='$_POST[detail]', Uren='$_POST[uren]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'";
mysqli_query($login, $UpdateQuery);
}
```

and in my `log.php` I have this code:

```
require_once('../includes/updel.php')
```

But when I try to load my `log.php`, without even pressing a button I get the javascript alert of:

```
Gebeurtenis field must be filled
```

I tried a lot of things but I don't know what causes this problem. Can anyone help me out?

If needed, this is my code for submitting the form:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
?>
 <form action="log" method="post" name="Form">
 <tr>
 <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>">
 <td>
 <?php echo $row['Date']?> 
 </td>
 <td>
 <textarea name="detail" cols="170" rows="3"><?php echo $row['Detail']?></textarea>
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="number" name="uren" min="1" max="10" value="<?php echo $row['Uren']?>">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="fa fa-pencil button alterar">
 </td>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="fa fa-trash button excluir">
 </td>
 </tr>  
 </form>
```

Comment: are u using form inside the while loop?

Comment: Yes, so it shows a lot of data through this way. Why you asked? :)

Comment: is @tewdyn code work ??? or still have same issue?

Comment: It worked thanks for asking.

Comment: You shouldnt close the question, I was about to answer it. You need learn to listen critics.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I asked the question little bit wrong that's why I closed it. I thank you for the critics though. I have to change some things in my code first. Can we talk through PM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check if the form actually has been submitted. To do so use `if(isset())`

```
if(isset($_POST['detail']) && isset($_POST['dren'])){
  $text = $_POST['detail'];
  $uren = $_POST['uren'];
  if (empty($text )) {
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Gebeurtenis field must be filled\")</script>";
  }
  else if (empty($uren)){
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Uren field must be filled\")</script>";
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to detect a post, then don't test for the presence/absence of a specific field. `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` is 100% reliable, and doesn't care if any fields were submitted at all.

Comment: @MarcB maybe there are some optional fields. In this case you'd have to use `isset()` to make sure that all requiered inputs have been submitted

Comment: @Tewdyn How would I make this work now? Can you check the post I've edited? It doesn't work with the update fields anymore? It just updates even though the fields are empty.

Comment: check you code on  [code] 
 <form action="log"  maybe this : [code]
 <form action="log.php"  method="post" name="form">

Comment: No @BlackHack123 It has to do with something else. I have in my htaccess that I can call my files without .php

Comment: then the answer of @Tewdyn it's  ok you could validate if isset the post only with a if(isset($value)){//your code if exist this $value}